# Youtube video with hyphen not working in IOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I am using Cordova YoutubeVideoPlayer Plugin in my ionic project. It works well in android.But in IOS, it is not working with video id having a hyphen(-) in it(eg: "6L-ZHjUhcQY"). It works fine with all other urls. How can I solve this.

```
.controller('menuController', function () {
    var id = "6L-ZHjUhcQY";
    YoutubeVideoPlayer.openVideo(id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the debugger, are the video ids with hyphens correctly saved in the variable? It might be a character encoding issue, or an issue with the plug-in itself.

Comment: yes, Id is correctly saved. Is there any other plugin I can use instead of this.

Comment: For me personally, I use youtube-dl. It downloads youtube videos so I never experience buffer and can view offline.

Comment: I just want to play it, no need to download it

Comment: iYoutube Unity iOS Plugin looks promising.

Comment: Is this a cordova plugin? Could you please provide a link.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the ios issue by updating some files
https://github.com/fingentffts/CordovaYoutubeVideoPlayer

Now I found some issue in android tabs.

Videos are playing even if the screen is locked. And also hyphen video are not playing in samsung tab.

Answer (score 0):

android issue also fixed by editing code in YoutubeVideoPlayer.java file in plugin

```
private Intent createYoutubeIntent(String videoId) {
//  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        Intent intent;
        Context cordovaContext = cordova.getActivity();
        String version = YouTubeIntents.getInstalledYouTubeVersionName(cordovaContext);
        if(version != null && version.startsWith("11.16") && YouTubeIntents.canResolvePlayVideoIntent(cordovaContext)) {
            intent = YouTubeIntents.createPlayVideoIntent(cordovaContext, videoId);
        } else {
            if(YouTubeIntents.canResolvePlayVideoIntentWithOptions(cordovaContext)){
                intent = YouTubeIntents.createPlayVideoIntentWithOptions(cordovaContext, videoId, true, true);
            } else {
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + videoId), cordovaContext, YouTubeActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("videoId", videoId);
                ConfigXmlParser parser = new ConfigXmlParser();
                parser.parse(cordovaContext);
                CordovaPreferences prefs = parser.getPreferences();
                intent.putExtra("YouTubeApiId", prefs.getString("YouTubeDataApiKey","YOUTUBE_API_KEY"));
            }
        }
        return intent;
//  }

    //return new Intent(null, Uri.parse("ytv://" + videoId), cordova.getActivity(), OpenYouTubePlayerActivity.class);
}
```